# How do i get a specific word phrase out of a word soup with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I already sorted my code with BeautifulSoup and come out with this:

```
<bound method Tag.prettify of <script type="text/javascript">var LifeTimeStats = [{"Key":"Top 3","Value":"31"},{"Key":"Top 5s","Value":"36"},{"Key":"Top 3s","Value":"13"},{"Key":"Top 6s","Value":"27"},{"Key":"Top 12s","Value":"76"},{"Key":"Top 25s","Value":"58"},{"Key":"Score","Value":"99,788"},{"Key":"Matches Played","Value":"502"},{"Key":"Wins","Value":"9"},{"Key":"Win%","Value":"2%"},{"Key":"Kills","Value":"730"},{"Key":"K/d","Value":"1.48"}];</script>>
```

I am trying to get the specific Value **"730"**
from this :

`{"Key":"Kills","Value":"730"}`

As there are no HTML tags I can sort by. I have no idea, how to get this specific value. Do you have any idea?

Maybe there is another solution to get there...
Here is the full code:

```
#----WEB INPUT BASIC----

    #import bs4
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


    #setting my url
    url = 'https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/psn/Rehgum'

    #making my https page work
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
    webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
    urlopen(req).close()

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

    lifetime = page_soup.findAll("script",{"type":"text/javascript"})

    stats = lifetime[3]

    specific = stats.prettify

    value = specific.text

    #from here there is just code to put that value in a .txt file
```

Comment: Does you text really contains *bound method Tag.prettify of*?

Comment: Just a suggestion.. But wouldn't it be easier to apply for an [API key](https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api)?

Just make a request to ```https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/psn/Rehgum``` and get the stats you need. No parsing required. It'll also be faster, since you're not loading the whole page.

Comment: Hi @AlexOsheter, you are totally right !! API-key would be the easiest thing to just get the raw data of the fortnitetracker.. but i used this as an exercise for myself to learn something about webscraping. I had the problem with not by beautiful soup sortable tags earlier on other examples that i made for myself, so this totally useful. thanks for your comment ! it's absolutely right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea of what you could do:

1. Extract the JS code into a Python variable.
2. Make a regex operation extracting the value of the variable.
3. "JSONify" such variable value.
4. Extract the data you need.

As an extract:

```
a = '''var LifeTimeStats = [{"Key":"Top 3","Value":"31"},{"Key":"Top 5s","Value":"36"},{"Key":"Top 3s","Value":"13"},{"Key":"Top 6s","Value":"27"},{"Key":"Top 12s","Value":"76"},{"Key":"Top 25s","Value":"58"},{"Key":"Score","Value":"99,788"},{"Key":"Matches Played","Value":"502"},{"Key":"Wins","Value":"9"},{"Key":"Win%","Value":"2%"},{"Key":"Kills","Value":"730"},{"Key":"K/d","Value":"1.48"}];'''

b = re.findall(r'var.*?=\s*(.*?);', a)[0]
c = json.loads(b)
```

See the [dummy full code](https://repl.it/@kazbeel/SO-50018614) I wrote.

**UPDATE**

After seeing the full code... [This](https://repl.it/@kazbeel/SO-50018614-2) could be a solution for your problem.

Comment: Hey kazbeel, 

Thanks for your fast reply !
i extracted the code into a python variable and tried to get the regex operation to run, but without success :( 

"the dummy full code" is a 404 page :x ...i am a total beginner with python :x ... 
i edited my post and added the complete code... maybe there is another way to get to the result ?

Comment: @Sh0x Sorry for the 404 page. I messed it up. After seeing your full code I could make a quick script that might solve your problem.

Comment: omg. that script in your link is actually working ! you are a hero ! ... i tried to paste it in my script, but instead of using the "a=#hardcoded" i want to use my var from the output ("specific").
when i set in the "specific" var instead of hardcoding it in "a=" i get an error ... any idea on that?

Comment: @Sh0x Take a look at the update link or here -> https://repl.it/@kazbeel/SO-50018614-2

Comment: oh.. my fault .. sorry, i'm totally new on stackoverflow :x...
this worked! if prints the value in the console! ... 

but it still won't print the output of "('Num kills = {}'.format(num_kills))" to my textfile ... 

If you could have a last short look into that i would love to donate you some for your favorite icecream on paypal :x ...

full code: https://pastebin.com/rrL5kug2

Comment: still getting the same error when i run the script (the "lifetime_wins.txt" does not change either)

Console err:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "danke.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "danke.py", line 8, in main
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 98, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'

Comment: well, i think it is just me... still not found the issue, but when i run in in repl.it it works fine.... let me know you paypal for the promised icecream :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working!
The thing that produced my errors was the "def loop():" part.

Here is the final working code:

```
def loop():
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import json
    import re
    import time


    #setting my url
    url = 'https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/psn/Rehgum'

    #making my https page work
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
    webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
    urlopen(req).close()

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

    lifetime = page_soup.findAll("script",{"type":"text/javascript"})

    stats = lifetime[3]

    stats_var = re.findall(r'var.*?=\s*(.*?);', stats.text)[0]

    vals = json.loads(stats_var)

    for val in vals:
        if val['Key'] == 'Kills':
            num_kills = val['Value']
            break

    print('Num kills = {}'.format(num_kills))

    with open('lifetime_wins.txt', 'w') as fd:
        fd.write(str(num_kills))

    time.sleep(30)

    loop()


for i in range(1,2):
        loop()

while i<1:
    print ("Ende")
```

Big "Thank you" to @kazbeel. You saved my Day! +rep